# using rvalue reference in + operator

Tags: c++

I read [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/rvalue-references-c0x-features-in-vc10-part-2/) and then tried to write a class(a dummy string class) where I can try to see the benefit of rvalue reference as explained in that document.

but I dont see my +(&&) operator getting called.
theoretically && based + operator should be getting called to capture the rvalue reference to (str2 + "test") part of the str2 + "test" + str2 expression.

code is below:

```
class Test
{
    public:
    Test()
    {
        cout << "\nctor called";
    }
    
    Test(Test& obj)
    {
        cout << "\ncopy ctor called";
    }
    
    Test(Test&& rvalue_exp)
    {
        cout << "\nrvalue exp called";
    }
    
    Test operator+(const char* str)
    {
        cout << "\noperator + called " << str;
    }
    
    Test operator+(const Test& str)
    {
        cout << "\noperator +& called";
    }
    
    Test operator+(Test&& str)
    {
        cout << "\noperator +&& called";
    }
    
    void operator=(const Test& str)
    {
        cout << "\noperator + called";
    }
};

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World";
    Test str, str2;
    str = str2 + "test" + str2;
    return 0;
}

output:
Hello World
ctor called
ctor called
operator + called test
operator +& called
operator + called
```

So my question is as per the theory in that document I linked how can the user benefit from && in my + operator ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing

```
Test operator+(Test&& str)
```

and

```
Test& operator+(const Test& str) &&
```

`str = str2 + "test" + str2;` has no rvalues on the right side, arguments of the `operator+`.

For calling your operator try this:

```
str = str1 + (str2 + "test");
```

Also note, your operator returns an invalid type, it should return a reference.

Your operators promise to return values, but actually do not return anything. This results in undefined behavior.

Comment: great! the only change i did was : str = str2 + (str2 + "test");
and I see the +(&&) operator getting called, but why did the +(&&) operator is not getting called when I do str = (str2 + "test") + str2 ?

Comment: Because `(str2 + "test")` is rvalue on the left side, `Test&& str` is a right side argument, `str2` on the right side is lvalue.

Comment: Also where do i find the documentation for the construct:

Test& operator+(const Test& str) &&

where  && is at the end ?

Comment: On https://cppreference.com

Comment: but what is the difference && being at the end vs the way i have written ?

Comment: && applied to the operator means `Test* const this` points to a rvalue reference Test&&.

Comment: Ok got it, but does the std::string class now has && based + operators ?

Comment: But why does the real std::string class not use && at the end, it declares its + operator on all combinations using rhs, lhs https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B

Comment: @stng Whether you write a free function `operator+(lhs, rhs)` or a member function `ClassOfLhs::operator+(rhs)` is a matter of style. Many believe that a free function should be preferred compared to a member function if both can achieve the same goal for various reasons you can find on SO.  The standard chose to make `operator+` a free function. You can also find more information about this `&&` at the end at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#Member_functions_with_ref-qualifier